# ¿Cómo ejecutar una funcion dentro de una tabla en html?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
   <table style="width:100%">

        <tr>

            <td>{{!! $max4.".".$max5.".".$max6!!}}

                <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="4">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">Celda tabla principal (padre)</td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="6">
                                <tr>
                                     <script>crearTabla({{!! $max4.".".$max5.".".$max6!!}});</script>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> Tabla anidada, Celda (2,1) <td>
                                    <td> Tabla anidada, Celda (2,2) <td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table></td>

            <td>{{!! $max10.".".$max11.".".$max12!!}}</td>

            <td>{{!! $max16.".".$max17.".".$max18!!}}</td>

            <td>{{!! $max22.".".$max23.".".$max24!!}}</td>


        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>{{!! $max1.".".$max2.".".$max3!!}}</td>

            <td>{{!! $max7.".".$max8.".".$max9!!}}</td>

            <td>{{!! $max13.".".$max14.".".$max15!!}}</td>

            <td>{{!! $max19.".".$max20.".".$max21!!}}</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td id="id1">P.TERMINADO</td>

            <td>P.TERMINADO</td>

            <td>P.TERMINADO</td>

            <td>P.TERMINADO</td>

        </tr>



    </table>
```

Y deseo que en cada celda, donde pongo los "max" se ejecute una función que cree otra tabla dentro de ésta, y que se creen las celdas pertinentes, dependiendo de max. Mi función se llama crearTabla y está declarada así:

function crearTabla(maximo) {

```
        var nombres = maximo.split(".");
        max1 = nombres[0];
        max2 = nombres[1];
        max3 = nombres[2];
        console.log(max1);
        for (i=0;i<=max2;i++)
        {
            document.write("<td>i</td>");
        }
    }
```

El funcionamiento no es el esperado, ¿alguna idea?.

Gracias de antemano,
Rosa.

Comment: Javascript no se ejecuta fuera de los tags `<script>` o los atributos `onclick`, `onmouseover`...

Comment: Solventado ese error, pero sigue sin funcionar como esperaba. Gracias.

Comment: Échale un ojo al siguiente enlace, lo tienes en español. https://www.ubiquitour.com/QkZXLD6Z/